# Pass Java Class<?> as body of rest template

Tags: java, spring, rest, parameter-passing

i'm implementing a service which exposes a POST endpoint. This service queries a noSql database (MongoDB, but i think it does not metter) and has to return a List of java objects of a generic Class. Now, my aim is to pass to this service only 2 params: a query string and a Class object in order to build a generic parser. My question is: how am i suppose to pass a Class object inside the Json payload of a Post http call? I am not sure is possible, it think the only way to do that would be through a Byte[] or something like that. But how could i rebuild then, in the RestController, the Class object?

***Edit***

Client side code sample:

```
    public static List<CustomObject> getData(String token, String query) {

    try {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        restTemplate.setErrorHandler(new HttpErrorHandler());
        //BUILD HEADERS
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
        headers.add("Authorization", token);
        //BUILD BODY 
        JsonObject body_obj = new JsonObject();
        body_obj.addProperty("query", query);
        body_obj.addProperty("class", CustomObject.class);
        HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(body_obj.toString(), headers);

        ParameterizedTypeReference<List<CustomObject>> responsetype = new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<CustomObject>>() {
        };
        ResponseEntity<List<CustomObject>> s = restTemplate.exchange(endpoint+"/getData", HttpMethod.POST, entity, responsetype);

        return s.getBody();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("returning empty Map, see error handler logs for error info..");
        return new ArrayLsit<CustomObject();
    }
}
```

This performs a post forcing a List as return type.

On the server side..

```
    @PostMapping("/getData")
public ResponseEntity<List<? extends Serializable> getCognitiveData(String body, HttpServletRequest req) {

    log.info("Start /getData");

    String token = parseToken(req);

    List<? extends Serializable> ret = processBody(body);

    log.info("/getData - got "+ret.size()+" elements");

    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(ret);

}
```

In the parseBody method, i would like to build the generic class ? extends serializable using the fields tha are contained in the Class object. The point is how to pass the Class object within the Json body.

**Edit 2**
Is there a way to achieve this without mapping the Objects i'm returning on the server side?

Comment: Can you give an example of what the call would look like client-side, and what you would like to happen server-side when it is received? Have you thought of using reflection to convert from a string representation of the class name to the actual class object?

Comment: @tucuxi i edited the question. I think reflection is the right way to do this, but i don't know how to pass the Class object.

Comment: @Imaguest i took a look at the guide you posted, but looks like you need a definition o the classes you want to use, i don't want to any definition. What i need is a generic "object of a generic class builder", without knowing what i'm building

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution would be to use the "fully qualified class name" of the class, which is a `String`. This can easily be sent in a JSON.

For example:

A quick utility class:

```
public class Payload {
    private String query;
    private String className;

    // getters and setters
}
```

In your controller, you get the class value using `Class.forName()`:

```
@RequestMapping(...)
public void foo(@RequestBody Payload payload) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    Class c = Class.forName(payload.getClassName());
    doSomething(c, payload.getQuery());
}
```

Comment: This implies that on the server side i need to map all the objects i'm dealign with, and i don't want to. As i explained above, i need an object of generic class builder, whitout knowing what i'm building. Is it possible or do i need to map all the classes i'm dealing with on th server side too? i think i don't have any choice..

Comment: there is no need to "map" anything there. The class is instantiated at run-time, and there are very few limits to what you can achieve via reflection. Which makes it dangerous in the wrong hands: make sure you validate your inputs, and ideally have a white-list of what classes you allow requests to instantiate

Comment: Ok my bad, i misunderstood the @cameron1024 answer. I'll take it as good. Thank you very much to both :)